# mssql_execute fails from php

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

When I try to call a procedure from php using mssql_execute, it fails.

But when I try calling it from SQL server studio tool, the same works with same parameters.

The execution time is bit higher, but it works,

There is no error shown on PHP side, but if I write a die like

```
mssql_execute($stms) or die('Not Working');
```

the die works.

What might be the reason for this?

```
mssql_get_last_message()
```

returns NULL

Comment: mssql_get_last_message() returns null

Comment: Then elaborate on your prepared proc query. Otherwise I don't think there's a generic reason for working in a frontend but not over PHPs interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by increasing the value in php.ini

```
mssql.timeout = 120;
```

Which was `mssql.timeout = 60;` before.